# JavaFX 2: How to load stylesheet into a Scene subclass distributed as part of a library?

Tags: java, css, stylesheet, javafx

I'm subclassing many of the JavaFX 2 classes to distribute them as part of a library that will be used by others. This requires that a stylesheet (part of the library) be applied to all instances of MySceneClass (not it's real name :-) ), and I can't find the right path magic. I've tried variants of:

```
mySceneInstance.getStylesheets.addAll("/com/mine/css/MySceneClass.css")
```

where com.mine.css is a package of the library: Variants I've tried include no leading slash, trimming the leading part of the path, probably a few others. But I always get the message:

```
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheet Resource "/com/mine/css/MySceneClass.css" not found.
```

I've also tried putting a stub Css class into the css package, and then using

```
com.mine.css.Css.getResource("Scene.css")
```

to fetch a URL that I can pass to ...getStyleSheets.addAll(...), but when I do so I get a message like:

```
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheet Resource "../css/Scene.css" not found.
```

which is very confusing, as getResource seems to be correctly identifying the file, but I still can't load it.

This is on the current dev preview on OS X (I believe the version is 2.1 09).

Thanks for any help,
Ken

Comment: Sorry, I made one mistake in the above: com.mine.css.Css.getResource("Scene.css") returned null, not a string.

Answer (score 12):

I've only had luck with this syntax as found in the Ensemble sample:

```
scene.getStylesheets().addAll(Ensemble2.class.getResource("ensemble2.css").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: This answer is generally correct, and should be upvoted. It does not apply to the original questioner's specific circumstance, which ended up being a tooling issue.

Answer (score 3):

Finally tracked down the problem to Intellij IDEA CE which, by default, does *not* recognize css files as a resource that needs to be copied from the source to the target dir. Adding a *.css pattern to list of recognized resource types fixed the problem.