# How to load css file in javafx8

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

This code is not working in javafx 8

```
  scene.getStylesheets().add("appCssFile.css");
```

I get the `Exception`

```
Mar 25, 2014 12:21:20 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser reportException
WARNING: Please report java.lang.NumberFormatException at:
Mar 25, 2014 12:21:20 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "appCssFile.css" not found.
```

How can I load the css ?

Comment: Maybe this helps
[CSS loading problem with javafx][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010989/javafx-2-how-to-load-stylesheet-into-a-scene-subclass-distributed-as-part-of-a

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need an URL and call toExternalForm in order to load a css file into your project.
Use the ClassLoader for that:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case ,I want to load a css file from disk and I do it as this [article](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/04/use-external-css-files-javafx/) said and it worked for me. code snippet as follow:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("file:///E:/csse2002-7023/src/csse2002/block/world/main.css")
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Using Paths you get the the same result with: 

     Paths.get("E","csse2002-7023","src","csse2002","block","world","main.css").toUri().toString())

Answer (score 2):

For those who can't find css the way from accepted answer use classLoader:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("css/style.css").toExternalForm()
```

If you use maven it will find your css under `resources/css/` dir.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add package name with .css file.

Your code will look like this:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("sample/appCssFile.css");
```