# Packaging an Eclipse Program With External Files

Tags: java, eclipse, build, package

I'm not sure if this was answered previously, I tried searching for the kind of question I am asking, but I couldn't find something satisfactory. If someone could point me to a similar question, that would help.

What I am trying to do is to package an eclipse program that has external files, such as images, into a single file, rather than a jar file and the supporting files placed in the same directory.

I am not sure if that is even possible, but is there some way in eclipse that would allow you to somehow package the external files along with the jar file in a single, neat file that can be executed easily?

---

EDIT:

Thanks to ortis and Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, I figured out how to do it. Here are the steps for working it out:

1. Firstly, ensure that all of your external files are in your src folder, not in your bin or workspace or whatever else. If you have packages in your project, they will appear as folders and the external files must be placed into those folders for use within that package.
2. As for calls to the external files, don't do something like this:

   ```
   Image img = new Image("fileName");
   ```

   Rather do this:

   ```
   Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("fileName"));
   ```

   while ensuring that "fileName" is in the src folder or package folder, if you have packages.

Some points:

-If you are initializing a global variable using a file name that is outside of your main constructor or function call, getClass(), won't work. Use:

```
yourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("fileName");
```

-if your using JavaFX Scenebuilder and you need to package your external CSS file, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010989/javafx-2-how-to-load-stylesheet-into-a-scene-subclass-distributed-as-part-of-a) is a solution that will help you load the style sheet in your program instead of using the .fxml file to do it.

-An InputStream variable can be assigned the result of

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("fileName"));
```

and be used instead of the whole mess.

Comment: You can package all ressource (image, sound, ...) in the Jar and publish the whole program as a single Jar file. But to work, you would have to use relative path in you code. Check `Class.getRessourceAsStream`

Comment: Just put your ressource inside your project (you can create a dedicated folder to put all your ressources in it, or just put them in the java package, like a class). To access the file, try any tutorial on `Class.getRessourceAsStream`, it is pretty simple to use.

Comment: do you have export it as a jar file or a runnable jar file?

Comment: Both will work but since you are talking about program and not API, I guess you want to be able to run it, so runnable Jar should be better

Comment: I tried that but what I noticed was that I have about ~30MB of images but my jar file is only about ~300KB, so... I am not sure where the images are, but I am sure that they are not packaged with the jar file

Comment: Try to unzip the Jar and check if your images are in. Be sure to include the image in your project, like a regular class file (images must be somewhere inside the "src" folder of your project)

Comment: sorry for the delay, but I moved my external images into my src folder, they were previously in my bin folder, and into the proper package, like you said, and it worked when I exported everything. So thanks. I would mark your answer as correct but alas, it is a "comment", not an "answer"

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You must reference all external files as inputstreams instead (because you want the classloader to get them from inside a jar file), and then wrap the resulting single jar file as an EXE file using http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: supposing I reference all files as inputstreams, when I export my project as a jar file or a runnable jar file, should I end up with a file that contains all my image files?

Comment: Why reference anything as `InputStream` ? And why do you need launch4j ? double cliking on the jar file works just fine

Comment: Regarding InputStream, it may be used because getClass().getResourceAsStream("filename"); returns an InputStream variable. It is needed if you want to pass around the InputStream object instead of calling getClass().getResourceAsStream("filename");  everytime... I think so anyways

Comment: @ortis Due to the "rather than a jar file" wording.